# Passing a value from a dialog to its parent window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I created my own version of a Dialog class that is being used as a parent class for my different dialog windows that have custom fields.  At the bottom is the code for the Dialog class.  In one of the Dialog type windows there is a Combobox (drop down box) that allows the user to also enter their own value.  If they enter their own value (their name) and it isn't contained in the list of customers (from a file) it asks the user if they want to add a new customer.  If they select yes I want it to pass the name they entered up to the parent window (the root of the application), close the dialog box where they entered the name, and open a different dialog to enter the new customer's info (containing the name they entered before).  Every part of this works except passing the value up.  At first I attempted to pass the value up using a custom exception, which doesn't work because of how Tkinter handles exceptions.

How should I pass this value up?  My initial thought would be through a custom Tkinter Event.  I can't find information on how to do that though.

Root Method creating first child dialog:

```
def check_in(self):
    log_diag = LoggerDialog(self,self.customers)
    try:
        log_diag.show()
    except NewCustomerException, (instance):
        self.new_customer(str(instance))
    except:
        print instance
```

Inside Child Dialog Box:

```
def new_customer_error(self):
    #parse name and preset values in the new customer dialog
    name = self.name.get()

    if askquestion(title="New Customer?",
        message="Add new customer: " + name,
        parent = self.root) == 'yes':
        raise NewCustomerException(name)
```

Dialog class:

```
class Dialog:
    def __init__(self, master, title, class_=None, relx=0.5, rely=0.3):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.class_ = class_
        self.relx = relx
        self.rely = rely

    def setup(self):
        if self.class_:
            self.root = Toplevel(self.master, class_=self.class_)
        else:
            self.root = Toplevel(self.master)

        self.root.title(self.title)
        self.root.iconname(self.title)

    def enable(self):
        ### enable
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.wm_delete_window)
        self._set_transient(self.relx, self.rely)
        self.root.wait_visibility()
        self.root.grab_set()
        self.root.mainloop()
        self.root.destroy()

    def _set_transient(self, relx=0.5, rely=0.3):
        widget = self.root
        widget.withdraw() # Remain invisible while we figure out the geometry
        widget.transient(self.master)
        widget.update_idletasks() # Actualize geometry information
        if self.master.winfo_ismapped():
            m_width = self.master.winfo_width()
            m_height = self.master.winfo_height()
            m_x = self.master.winfo_rootx()
            m_y = self.master.winfo_rooty()
        else:
            m_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
            m_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
            m_x = m_y = 0
        w_width = widget.winfo_reqwidth()
        w_height = widget.winfo_reqheight()
        x = m_x + (m_width - w_width) * relx
        y = m_y + (m_height - w_height) * rely
        if x+w_width > self.master.winfo_screenwidth():
            x = self.master.winfo_screenwidth() - w_width
        elif x < 0:
            x = 0
        if y+w_height > self.master.winfo_screenheight():
            y = self.master.winfo_screenheight() - w_height
        elif y < 0:
            y = 0
        widget.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        widget.deiconify() # Become visible at the desired location

    def wm_delete_window(self):
        self.root.quit()
```

I tried using generate_event() and passing a custom parameter (name) and I get this error:

```
TclError: bad option "-name": must be -when, -above, -borderwidth, 
-button, -count, -data, -delta, -detail, -focus, -height, -keycode, 
-keysym, -mode, -override, -place, -root, -rootx, -rooty, -sendevent, 
-serial, -state, -subwindow, -time, -warp, -width, -window, -x, or -y
```

I've tried overriding the value of a few of these and I keep getting errors back telling me that I've passed the wrong type.  (mode is an int, detail has to be an instance of a specific list of objects)  This does not seem to be a very elegant solution.

**Here is the solution I settled on:**

Code in the child object (for handling a name not in database):

```
def new_customer_error(self):

    if askquestion(title="New Customer?",
        message="Add new customer: " + self.name.get(),
        parent = self.root) == 'yes':
        self.master.event_generate('<<NewCustomer>>')
```

In `__init__` of root window:
`self.bind('<<NewCustomer>>',self.new_customer)`

Later on in root object:

```
def new_customer(self, event=None):
    #if evert this came as a new customer entry through check in
    if event:
        temp = self.logger_diag.name.get().split(' ')
        self.newc_diag.fname.set(temp[0])
        if len(temp) == 2:
            self.newc_diag.lname.set(temp[1])
        elif len(temp) == 3:
            self.newc_diag.mname.set(temp[1])
            self.newc_diag.lname.set(temp[2])
        elif len(temp) > 3:
            self.newc_diag.mname.set(temp[1])
            self.newc_diag.lname.set(' '.join(temp[2:4]))
```